# Activiti : Copy active executions to different db

Tags: java, database, activiti

we want to copy active executions (and all related data) to different database. Is there some way that activiti API can help us? I have found API pro deleting, but not for copying. The selection key would be deployment.

We have shared workflow engine for multiple applications with multiple processes. Now we want to copy data for one of those application into our test environment, so users can test new release and we can test instance migration. Since we have execution ids in business data in separate database, we need to keep them.

Only way how I can imagine this is to split workflow engines and have separate database tables for each application. Then we would be able to simply copy database that is used just for the application. Split can be done quite easily, is we copy full current db and then delete deployments that are not related to current app.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an API method for that, but you can try to perform a migration of the ACT_RU_% tables. Those database tables contains the data necessary for all runtime (in progress) processes. 
I would follow this sequence:
   Copy all the users groups and their relations in ACT_ID_USER ACT_ID_GROUP and ACT_ID_MENBERSHIP
   Deploy the proccesses that you need to move to the other activity instance.
   Copy all the records in ACT_RU% tables related to those processes 
   Set all the database sequences to the max values recorded in the tables.